# Qt - Display animated GIF selected by QListWidget on MainWindow

Tags: c++, qt, animation, animated-gif, qt-designer

thank you in advance for reading and help.

I'm trying to make a GIF manager based on a QListWidget where you can select a GIF from the list (using on_*_itemClicked, as you can see below) and it will appear the animated GIF in the space below the list (or sideways, doesn't matter).

```
void MainWindow::on_listOfURL_itemClicked(QListWidgetItem *item)
{
    QLabel* lab = new QLabel(this);
    QMovie* mov = new QMovie(":/res/giftest/C:/Users/Rober/Desktop/giftest.gif");
    lab->setGeometry(200, 200, 200, 200);
    lab->setMovie(mov);
    lab->show();
    mov->start();
}
```

[GUI screenshot of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLuhI.png)

I've tried using the piece of code above, but it shows nothing. It is just a futile try of making it work, that's why the GIF path is the same, you needn't worry about it.

Honestly, I've search a lot of code in forums and this very website regarding GIFS and animations, and none of the things I've seen have worked for me.

How should I proceed? I guess I should use some graphics QWidget in the UI and link it with the function on_*_itemClicked so it takes the location of the image from the QListWidgetItem and displays where I pointed in the UI.

I've gotten the code pasted here by surfing the Mighty Google, and it brings me some doubts:

- I create a QLabel with the MainWindow as parent. Okay, but where will it appear?
- Can't I create in the Designer a widget that I can define where will it be and just make the GIF work?

I think I've explained myself correctly, if not just let me know.

EDIT: I think what I need is a QLabel that is inside the MainWindow, below the URL list. How do I shape that QLabel in QtDesigner and then take that same QLabel in code and manipulate it with the GIF?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to include into .pro

```
QTPLUGIN     +=  qgif
```

and show `label->show();`

Of course you can add things in designer. You can  add  custom widgets you create, but you need make special project that would make a "plugin" for Designer and build it in Release mode, then install plugin in proper plugin folder.
For that you should be sure, that those are added to .pro file:

```
CONFIG      += plugin
TEMPLATE    = lib
QT          += widgets uiplugin
```

Then you need to  declare and implement plugin  derived from QObject AND QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface.

DO CHECK validity: `mov->isValid()` Code that relies on external sources being good eventually becomes source of little disasters. Program either need  a plugin's .dll next to it or static plugin linked with it

When you installed Qt, you installed app called QtAssistant. Take advantage of it. It's great deal of help. as well as their forums and examples storage you got in Qt directory.  Qt5 got plugin example online: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tutorials-widgets-childwidget-example.html

Comment: I've included what you say, even the isValid(). Looks like the GIF is valid, but it isn't shown.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've found myself the answer. It was pretty silly actually:

I didn't realize I could select a QLabel created in QtDesigner using ui->label and manipulate it.

```
ui->label->setMovie(selectedGif);
      selectedGif->start();
      ui->label->show();
```

Novice mistakes...